# Time windowed join in Flink inconsistent?

Tags: java, apache-flink

After converting two datastreams to tables and doing a window join on a time attribute. This is described here: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/table/streaming/joins.html#time-windowed-joins

The code is something like:

```
class POJO{
   String col1;
   String col2;
   long timestamp;
   /// other POJO stuff
}

StreamTableEnvironment tableEnv = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getTableEnvironment(env);
List<POJO> lst1 = ArrayList of 6000 elements, timestamp in ascending order. //All timestamps in lst1 are the same as in lst2
List<POJO> lst2 = ArrayList of 6000 elements, timestamp in ascending order. //All timestamps in lst1 are the same as in lst2
DataStream<POJO> ds1 = env.fromCollection().assignTimestampsandWatermarks()
DataStream<POJO> ds2 = env.fromCollection().assignTimestampsandWatermarks()

tableEnv.registerDataStream("ds1", ds1, "col1, col2, timestamp.rowtime")
tableEnv.registerDataStream("ds2", ds2, "col1, col2, timestamp.rowtime")


Table joinedTable = table.querySQL("SELECT col1, col2 FROM ds1 d1, ds2 d2 WHERE d1.col1 = d2.col1 AND d1.timestamp = d2.timestamp");

DataStream<POJO> joinedDS = tableEnv.toAppendStream(tableEnv.scan(joinedTable, POJO.class));

env.execute("Start pipeline");
```

Assume that `lst1` and `lst2` `POJO` objects have a one-to-one mapping in temrs of `timestamp` and `col1`, so after a join there should be `6000` elements.

The problem is, if I run this program 2 times, the number of items in the final `joinedDS` datastream are NOT the same! Sometimes there is total of 5951 elements, sometimes 5987, etc.. The number of events should always be `6000` assuming the `d1.col1 = d2.col1` and `d1.timestamp = d2.timestamp` always holds true. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: This should not happen and looks like a bug. Would you mind creating an issue in Flink's Jira? Thank you.

Comment: @FabianHueske, sure I will create an issue ASAP. Thanks